# how to express this special array assertion in code?

Tags: java, junit, testng, fest, assertj

I am currently using FEST or AssertJ for assertion.
and I run into a knot that I want to assert the flowing array:

```
[1,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

So how do I write the assertion like

```
assertThat(arr).contains(1,atIndex(0)).containsTheOthers(2)
```

I don't see containsOthers in FEST or I miss something equal?
I am a bit surprise FEST or AssertJ can't assert a range of index start from some designated index, since them emphasize on fluent concise assertion code. 
or is there good alternative?

As far I have to separate it into two asserts and manually fetch out first element to check and the n fetch out the others to check,totally three lines.  That's a mess.

```
assertThat(arr[0]).contains(1,atIndex(0));
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,1,arr.length);
assertThat(arr).containsOnly(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using AssertJ, I would write:

```java
assertThat(arr).containsExactly(1,2,2,2,2,2,2);
```

But note that it will also check the elements order.

FYI, AssertJ also provide these "contains" assertions:

- containsSequence
- containsSubSequence
- containsOnlyOnce

Have a look at the [int array assertions javadoc](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIntArrayAssert.html#method_summary)

Answer (score -1):

Why complicate things? The simplest way to write this would be:

```
assertEquals(new int[]{1,2,2,2,2,2,2}, arr);
```

Otherwise, if there can be any number of 2s, your second solution to split it into two assertions seems sensible.